# Theme Option not Working Inside a Function

Tags: pagination, next

Earlier, I asked [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/55159/allow-users-to-choose-pagination-or-next-previous-combine) and received a code which *should* work.  Unfortunately, this code is not working.

> I'm building a themes option panel and want users to be able to choose between Next/Previous links or pagination in my archives and homepage.

The code within `functions.php` is controlling an options panel drop-down which allows the user to choose pagination or next/previous links.

**This code is displaying Next/Previous links at all times, even when I choose pagination.  I need the pagination option to work too!**

What I have in `functions.php`

```
array( "name" => "Paginate or next/previous links?", 
    "desc" => "Choose your option", 
    "id" => $shortname."_next_prev_or_paginate", 
    "type" => "select", 
    "options" => array("Next", "Pagination"), 
    "std" => "Next"),
```

What I have in `archives.php`

```
<?php
function my_theme_navigation() 
{ 
    global $shortname;

    if( get_option( $shortname . '_next_prev_or_paginate' ) == 'Next' ) : 
        // the block for next-prev navigation 
        previous_posts_link ('Newer');
        next_posts_link('Older');
    else : 
        // the block for pagination
        global $wp_query; 
        $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer       
        echo paginate_links( 
            array( 
                'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', get_pagenum_link( $big ) ), 
                'format' => '?paged=%#%', 
                'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ), 
                'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages 
            ) 
        ); 
    endif; 
}
?>
```

### For all relevant codes...

The original pagination code (which has been combined with prev/next)

```
<?php
global $wp_query;

$big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer

echo paginate_links( array(
    'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', get_pagenum_link( $big ) ),
    'format' => '?paged=%#%',
    'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
    'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages
) );
?>
```

The previous/next which has been combined with pagination

```
<?php previous_posts_link ('Newer') ?>
<?php next_posts_link('Older') ?>
```

The function for the theme options, chooses between pagination and next/prev links

```
array( "name" => "Paginate or next/previous links?", 
    "desc" => "Choose your option", 
    "id" => $shortname."_next_prev_or_paginate", 
    "type" => "select", 
    "options" => array("Next", "Pagination"), 
    "std" => "Next"),
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1)** Move the function to the `functions.php` file, that's where it belongs. Put it at the end before any closing `?>`:

```
function my_theme_navigation() 
{ 
    global $shortname;

    if( get_option( $shortname . '_next_prev_or_paginate' ) == 'Next' ) : 
        // the block for next-prev navigation 
        previous_posts_link ('Newer');
        next_posts_link('Older');
    else : 
        // the block for pagination
        global $wp_query; 
        $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer       
        echo paginate_links( 
            array( 
                'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', get_pagenum_link( $big ) ), 
                'format' => '?paged=%#%', 
                'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ), 
                'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages 
            ) 
        ); 
    endif; 
}
```

**2)** Looks like the **only thing** you're **missing** is the **function call**, that will **print the navigation**.
Not very familiar with `archives.php`, so using `single.php` as example:

```
<?php
/**
 * The Template for displaying all single posts.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Eleven
 * @since Twenty Eleven 1.0
 */

get_header(); ?>

        <div id="primary">
            <div id="content" role="main">

                <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                    <nav id="nav-single">
                    <?php my_theme_navigation(); /* CALLING THE FUNCTION TO ECHO THE NAVIGATION */ ?>
                    </nav><!-- #nav-single -->

                    <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'single' ); ?>

                    <?php comments_template( '', true ); ?>

                <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

            </div><!-- #content -->
        </div><!-- #primary -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

---

#### Original answer

> ### Hypothesis
>
> **If**, as the question says,
>
> > this code is displaying Next/Previous links at **all times**
>
> <sup>*(My emphasis)*</sup>   It much probably means that the `if/else`
> is not working.
>
> ---
>
> ### Option Value
>
> ***Supposing*** `$shortname` is equal to `"shortname"`, I created an option in the table `wp_options`.   [image: phpMyAdmin]
>
> ---
>
> ### Test
>
> ***Putting*** this code in `header.php`, inside `<div id="main">` from TwentyEleven:
>
> ```
> function my_theme_navigation() { 
>   if( 'Next' == get_option( 'shortname_next_prev_or_paginate' ) ) : 
>       // the block for next-prev navigation 
>       echo 'Previous/Next selected.';
>   else : 
>       // the block for pagination
>       echo 'Pagination selected.';
>   endif; 
> }
> my_theme_navigation();
> ```
>
> ---
>
> ### Result and Possible Solution
>
> **It does** echo correctly when the option value is manually changed in the database.
>
> Make sure the following functions/commands are working in this order:
>
> 1. `get_option`, does it grabs the value? The value exists in the database?
> 2. `paginate_links`, does it prints correctly if called alone? Without `get_option` and `if/else`?
> 3. `if/else`, if the previous are working this one **gotta** be working

Comment: @siouxfan45 : It does not compute..! How on earth are you "*building a theme options panel*" without knowing "*nothing about PHP*"¿? ... I strongly suggest you to locate **all the relevant code** and add it to your Question. Unfortunately, seeing the final rendered Html doesn't help....

Comment: Thus far, I've done it by asking questions and combining a ton of tutorials online.  I've added what I believe is the relevant codes.

Comment: @siouxfan45 : Debugging PHP values with `echo`, `var_dump` and `print_r` are of extreme help. This is a simple test ( http://pastebin.com/GeMEnELT ), put it in `archives.php` and check the results when you change the theme option value (`"Paginate or next/previous links?"`).

Comment: The code provided is displaying the correct Option value when I switch it in theme options.  The code displays next/prev and pagination.  As shown here: http://themeforward.com/demo2/?cat=50  - How do I turn this into a functional code to choose between my next/prev links or pagination?

Comment: If I finally understand correctly, you are only missing the function call to print the selected navigation, answer updated, is this it?